# Errors installing IJulia: Homebrew and Nettle

Tags: macos, homebrew, julia

I recently tried installing IJulia on OS X 10.6.8, with Julia v0.2.1. After installing IPython, I ran `Pkg.build("IJulia")` and got the following console errors:

```
julia> Pkg.build("IJulia")
INFO: Building Homebrew
INFO: Cloning brew from https://github.com/staticfloat/homebrew.git
Cloning into '/Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Homebrew/deps/usr'...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Julia-0.2.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https
  Reason: Incompatible library version: git-remote-https requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 6.0.0
==============================[ ERROR: Homebrew ]===============================

brew_prefix! not defined
at /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Homebrew/src/Homebrew.jl:200
at /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Homebrew/deps/build.jl:1

================================================================================
```

It seems to be complaining about an old version of libcurl (?), but when I run `curl -V` in Terminal, it says I am using curl 7.19.7. Likewise, executing `ipython --version` shows that I'm using 2.0.0, the latest version of IPython. Am I misreading the error message? If so, what steps should I take to fix it?

#### Additional Errors

In addition to the error text I pasted above, it also printed the following:

```
INFO: Building Nettle
INFO: Attempting to Create directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/downloads
INFO: Directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/downloads already created
INFO: Downloading file http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/archive/nettle-2.7.1.tar.gz
INFO: Done downloading file http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/archive/nettle-2.7.1.tar.gz
INFO: Attempting to Create directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/src
INFO: Directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/src already created
INFO: Attempting to Create directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps
INFO: Directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps already created
INFO: Attempting to Create directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/src/nettle-2.7.1
INFO: Directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/src/nettle-2.7.1 already created
INFO: Attempting to Create directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/builds/nettle
INFO: Directory /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/builds/nettle already created
INFO: Changing Directory to /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/builds/nettle
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking for -R flag... none
Searching for libraries
checking /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/usr/lib... not found
checking /usr/local/lib... added
checking /sw/local/lib... not found
checking /sw/lib... not found
checking /usr/gnu/lib... not found
checking /opt/gnu/lib... not found
checking /sw/gnu/lib... not found
checking /usr/freeware/lib... not found
checking /usr/pkg/lib... not found
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/builds/nettle':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
===============================[ ERROR: Nettle ]================================

failed process: Process(`/Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/src/nettle-2.7.1/configure --disable-openssl --libdir=/Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/usr/lib --prefix=/Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/usr`, ProcessExited(77)) [77]
at /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2/Nettle/deps/build.jl:35

================================================================================
INFO: Building ZMQ
INFO: Building IJulia
Found IPython version 2.0.0 ... ok.
Creating julia profile in IPython...
(Existing KernelManager.kernel_cmd setting in ipython_config.py is untouched.)
(Existing IPythonWidget.execute_on_complete_input setting in ipython_qtconsole_config.py is untouched.)
(Existing FrontendWidget.lexer_class setting in ipython_qtconsole_config.py is untouched.)
(Existing NotebookApp.port setting in ipython_notebook_config.py is untouched.)
(Existing ipynblogo.png file untouched.)
(Existing ipynblogo.svg file untouched.)
(Existing favicon.ico file untouched.)
(Existing custom.js file untouched.)
(Existing julia.js file untouched.)

================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: Homebrew and Nettle had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in /Users/peterrichter/.julia/v0.2
 - build a package and all its dependencies with `Pkg.build(pkg)`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a C compiler installed so the Pkg.add is failing on some of IJulia's nettle dependency.

Your first errors dependency though looks like it's a linking conflict between the bundled git implementation for your julia distribution and the system provided library.

You can see exactly what shared library the git app is using with otool.

`otool -L /Applications/Julia-0.2.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https`

This should list the full path of the libcurl dylib that the git-remote-https binary is linking to.

You can compare that against the output for `otool -L $(which curl)` and see if they are linking to the same library.

You can also run `otool -L` on the referenced libraries themselves to see what versions they are. This should at least tell you what the conflict is. It's possible that you will need to upgrade the git version that your julia distribution uses. But I'm not sure what would be involved there. I just install julia from source which bypasses this particular problem.

You might find it easier to do the same.

Comment: Huh, that's odd, I use the C compiler on my computer all the time when calling Mathematica's `CCompile[]` (I have GCC installed)...

Comment: That is indeed odd then. Perhaps it's just bad environment setup somehow then.

Comment: It probably is, I don't really know how my file system and program interdependencies work too thoroughly, so I'll look into that. I appreciate the answer anyways!

Comment: For me on Linux I had a similar error and the problem was I was missing the gmp-devel package.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me might be of help to you:
Using latest Anaconda free python, download windows32 exe file from github and extract, start julia.bat, then in the Julia command window type Pkg.add("IJulia"), In another command window type
ipython notebook --profile=julia and enjoy the webpage that opens in your default browser(Chrome)!!
I had trouble because of the syntax of the --profile=julia command part.

Answer (score 1):

I too use macports and not Homebrew. 
I seem to have fixed this by changing lines 21,22 in ~/.julia/v0.3/Nettle/deps/build.jl to:

```
libdirs = String["$(julia_usrdir)/lib"; "/opt/local/lib"]
includedirs = String["$(julia_usrdir)/include"; "/opt/local/include"]
```

i.e. I added the macports lib and include dirs explicitly.

Can someone please notify the appropriate authorities, cheers.